# export {x as x} does not work with babeljs

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Why does this [pattern](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/wiki/Brief-Overview-of-ES6-Module-syntax#all-supported-syntax) end up in `undefined` when I try to import the module:

```
export {machines as machines} from './machines';
```

Comment: How are you exporting from `./machines`?

Comment: just like this: `export default function machines(state, action) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing

```
export default function machines(state, action) {}
```

then you have a `default` export, not a `named` export. `export default` exports an arbitrary expression, the fact that your function has the name `machines` has no effect on the export behavior. For that format, you would do

```
export {default as machines} from './machines';
```

With the `export ... from` format you have in your question, your export would have to be:

```
export function machines(state, action) {}
```